# Is there a way to show a UIelement that was previously hidden in earlier lines of code after a button has been tapped on the same VC in Swift?

Tags: swift, show, hidden, viewdidload, uielement

I have many UI elements on a VC including labels, textfields, and a button. In the viewDidLoad() function, most of the UI elements are initially hidden. I have successfully programmed the UIButton on the VC to change the label text and button title properties depending on what question is being asked. However, when I try to set a text property for a label or textfield that was previously hidden, it does not show back up. I saw on the apple dev website something about a hiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor view but am not sure if that's the solution. Is there an easy fix to this?

I tried creating a Boolean variable as var firstQuestionAsked = false and then setting it to true in the chunk of code when I want the UI elements to show again and setting the viewDidLoad code to an if-statement so that if the Bool is false, the elements are hidden but that didn't work.

// This is my code in the viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        aboveTopTextPrompt.text = aboveTopPrompt1
        topTextfield.placeholder = "Ex: 2.98"
        besideTopTextLabel.isHidden = true
        underTopTextLabel.isHidden = true
        aboveBottomTextPrompt.isHidden = true
        bottomTextfield.isHidden = true
        underBottomTextLabel.isHidden = true
        bottomFloatingLabel.isHidden = true
        darkButton.setTitle(nextTitle, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

// This is the portion of my code that is not working (in the button IBAction)

@IBAction func darkButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    if aboveTopPromptIndex == 1 {
        aboveTopTextPrompt.text = aboveTopPrompt2
        topTextfield.placeholder = "Ex: 76.00"
        besideTopTextLabel.isHidden = true
        underTopTextLabel.text = "string"
        aboveBottomTextPrompt.text = "string"
        bottomTextfield.isHidden = true
        underBottomTextLabel.isHidden = true
        bottomFloatingLabel.isHidden = true
        darkButton.setTitle(nextTitle, for: .normal)
        aboveTopPromptIndex = 2
    } else if aboveTopPromptIndex == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "darkViewToABC", sender: self)
    } else if (aboveTopPromptIndex == 5 || aboveTopPromptIndex == 6 {
        aboveTopPromptIndex = 7
        aboveTopTextPrompt.text = aboveTopPrompt7
        topTextfield.placeholder = "string"
        besideTopTextLabel.text = "string"
        underTopTextLabel.text = "string"
        aboveBottomTextPrompt.text = "string"
        bottomTextfield.placeholder = "string"
        underBottomTextLabel.text = "string"
        bottomFloatingLabel.text = "string"
        darkButton.setTitle(calculateTitle, for: .normal)
    }
```

The strings I set for the UI elements remain hidden. I did not show all of my code to avoid redundancy but basically, any placeholder or text property that was hidden previously does not become visible when I want it to and I do need them to show for one of the questions as shown in the last else if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someUIElement.isHidden = false` will make it visible.
The `isHidden` value determines whether the view is hidden or not. It won't be changed automatically by any means. So once you set it to `true`, it won't be visible again until you explicitly set it back to `false`